# Packet content of response after port forward

Tags: ip, router, nat, portforwarding

I thought I understood the whole thing about NAT etc but now I came to a problem.
First what I assumed:
Because there are not enough IPv4 addresses available we need another system.
The devices of today at home for connecting to the internet are a combination of:
1) A modem at the physical-level to change the type of signals on the wire. 
2) A switch at link-level so you can connect multiple computers to the device
3) A router to connect all the computers to the internet and go beyond your home-subnet etc.
4) A NAT to allow all the internal computers to connect to the outside
5) A portforwarder to let connections from the outside to the internal network

What I call a NAT:
When making a request to the outside: the NAT-part of the device changes the source-port and the source-ip of the request coming from an internal computer. The new source-ip will be your public-ip. The NAT-part will hold a record in a table with this mapping: "original-ip, original-port, new-port". 
When a reponse comes back, the NAT will check the destination-port and compare this with the new-ports is in his table. If it finds a match the NAT will replace the destination-ip with original-ip and new-port with original-port. As a consequence the response will be forwarded to the internal computer that made the request.
So, the NAT-part is for when a connection is initialized from the inside. When this request traverses the NAT, 2 things are changed: source-ip and source-port.

Then the portforwarder:
This part of the device will accept connections initialized in the outside-world to your network. It will look at the destination-port of the incoming request and by making a rule for that port-number it may change the destination-port and the destination-ip of the request to an internal ip. With these rules a request from the outside can connect to a computer on your internal network and thus the portforwarder changes 2 things: the destination-ip and the destination-port.

A: Before I ask my question, how is this explanation?

Now my problem is with the response after a request came from the outside through the portforwarder. Assume the right rules are made and a request came through portforwarding on an internal computer. So in the portforwarder the destination-ip was changed to the internal-ip of the computer and the destination-port was changed to the port where the service is running on. If this internal-computer is a webserver it will generate a response. So the destination-ip will be the request's source-ip and the destination-port will be the request's source-port. The source-ip will be the internal-ip of the computer and the source-port will be the port of the service.

Now that response has to go to the outside. So I assume it goes through the NAT to the outside?
So after passing the NAT, the source-ip will be the public-ip and the source-port will be random. Now I tested this with wireshark. I contacted a webserver behind a NAT and I saw the reponse was coming from port 80 ?! How is this possible? This indicates that the response of the forwarded request did not pass the NAT?

I rethought the concept and my new hypothesis is that when a connection is initialized from the outside, it will pass the portforwarder and reach the right computer. This will create a response and when this response reaches our "all-in-one"device, this device can recognize it forwarded the request of the response and will not change the source-port. 
B: Is this indeed the case or is it done in another way?

Wikipedia says about portforwarding: "The source address and port are, in this case, left unchanged. When used on machines that are not the default gateway of the network, the source address must be changed to be the address of the translating machine, or packets will bypass the translator and the connection will fail." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)

This confirms that the response of a forwarded request MUST go through the portforwarder again and not through the NAT so the source-port wont be changed. The portforwarder will change the source-ip to the public-ip.

Can someone verify this or give me another explanation than mine?

Answer (score 1):

> Now I tested this with wireshark. I contacted a webserver behind a NAT
>   and I saw the reponse was coming from port 80 ?! How is this possible?
>   This indicates that the response of the forwarded request did not pass
>   the NAT?

The webserver inside the NAT does not have to be running on port 80. It certainly is set up at the NAT to port forward and respond as if it were at port 80, but that doesn't mean much about the port the web server is actually running on.

Here is some ASCII "art" that may help.

```
**Internal Network**          **NAT Router**              **External Computer**
Web Server running at         IP 9.9.9.9 port 80          IP 20.20.20.20 
IP 192.168.1.7 port 4567      

                                                         Request web page at 9.9.9.9:80

                              Forwards port 80 traffic       
                              to 192.168.1.7:4567

Replies with the web page

                              Puts 9.9.9.9:80 in the 
                              source field and sends
                              the page on

                                                         Gets the page from "9.9.9.9:80" 
                                                         even though it actually came 
                                                         from 192.168.1.7:4567
```